# Data returned from urllib query is incorrectly encoded

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I am scraping some data from google images and have found that letters such as 'î' are being decoded incorrectly. In this case **'î'** becomes **'Ã®'**. I have stored data from a google query in an object and it's in the format of:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

however, the values of the dictionary can contain other characters such as:

```
{"key":"File:Blue tit (Cyanistes caeruleus), Parc du Rouge-Cloître, Brussels ( 32781868883).jpg"}
```

which when I received the data is in the form

```
{"key":"File:Blue tit (Cyanistes caeruleus), Parc du Rouge-Clo\xc3\xaetre, Brussels ( 32781868883).jpg"}
```

So the when I try to convert it to bytes and decode using:

```py
decoded_obj = bytes(raw_obj, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
```

I get the output

```
{"key":"File:Blue tit (Cyanistes caeruleus), Parc du Rouge-CloÃ®tre, Brussels ( 32781868883).jpg"}
```

The scrapers code is as follows:

```py
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Blue+tit+(Cyanistes+caeruleus),+Parc+du+Rouge-Clo%C3%AEtre,+Brussels+(32781868883).jpg&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE8866stfjAhWBolwKHQ1YCdQQ_AUIESgB&biw=1920&bih=937'

headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = str(response.read())

start_line = data.find('class="rg_meta notranslate">')
start_obj = data.find('{', start_line + 1)
end_obj = data.find('</div>', start_obj + 1)
raw_obj = str(data[start_obj:end_obj])

decoded_obj = bytes(raw_obj, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
final_obj = json.loads(decoded_obj)

print(final_obj)
```

Comment: So, you are getting hex values in your string. The question becomes converting those hex values to unicode or in your case, because of the i with a circumflex, the decoded format should be latin-1, not unicode escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response data consists of UTF-8 encoded bytes:

```
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
>>> res = response.read()
>>> type(res)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> response.headers
<http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x7ff6ea74ba90>
>>> response.headers['Content-type']                                                                                           
'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

The correct way to handle this is to decode the response data:

```
>>> data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Once this is done, `data` is a `str` and there is no need for any further decoding or encoding (or `str()` or `bytes()` calls).

In general, calling `str` on a `bytes` instance is the wrong thing to do, unless you provide the appropriate encoding:

```
>>> s = 'spam'
>>> bs = s.encode('utf-8')
>>> str(bs)
"b'spam'"   # Now 'b' is inside the string
>>> 

>>> str(bs, encoding='utf-8')
'spam'
```